# How to represent current user path in system()

Tags: objective-c, macos, shell, xcode4.5

I need to copy a file to current working user directory.

I did like this

```
NSString *filepath = @"~/Desktop";
NSString *filename = @"newFile";

int status=system([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"touch %@/%@", filePath, filename]UTF8String]);
```

But this is not creating a file on the Desktop.
Can some one tell me an alternate for '~' to get the current working user.

Comment: Problem with my code was that, before above lines I was executing a SUDO and turned my self to root. Thats was the reason I was not able to create the file in Users/myself/Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `getenv("HOME")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *filepath = [@"~/Desktop" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSString *filename = @"newFile";

int status=system([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"touch %@/%@", filepath, filename]UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `~` character does not have a meaning in the filesystem context, it has a meaning in the shell context and is substitute by `$HOME` as part of **Tilde Expansion**.  From the bash man:

> Tilde Expansion
>
> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character  (`~'),  all  of  the
>   characters  preceding  the  first unquoted slash (or all characters, if
>          there is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix.  If none  of
>          the  characters  in  the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the
>          tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible login  name.
>          If  this  login name is the null string, the tilde is replaced with the
>          value of the shell parameter HOME.  If HOME is unset, the  home  direc‐
>          tory  of  the  user executing the shell is substituted instead.  Other‐
>          wise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the home  directory  associated
>          with the specified login name.

So one solution is, as Dolda2000 suggested, use the `$HOME` instead of `~` but it does not work in the case of `~root` when the user is not root (root as an example in this case).

A more general solution is to invoque the shell in the `system` call.  I do not know objective-C, but it seams, with bash, it would look like:

```
int status=system([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bash -c 'touch %@/%@'", filePath, filename]UTF8String])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the users in in your machine

```
 for USER_DIR in $(ls /Users); 
    do { 
    *<write code here to implement something with each user>*;
    } 
    done;
```

This is a terminal command.
Works with *system()* in objective c.